# fetch a single postgres record as an associative array without using while loop

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

If I have a statement that I know will return only one result:

`$emp_query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'employee_id' LIMIT 1`"

Is there any way I can access the result of `pg_query($con, $csr_query);` as an associative array without using a `pg_fetch_assoc` and a while loop? A while loop seems unnecessary when I know I'm retrieving only one record. Maybe there is some way in PDO as well, I'm just setting it up this way first because I'm more comfortable with the simple way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like pg_fetch_result:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-result.php